# Почему при скачивании картинки через requests, некоторые картинки весят 1 килобайт?

Tags: python

```
count = 0
with open("w.txt", "r") as file:
for line in file:
    download = requests.get(line)
    count += 1
    with open(f'{count}.jpg','wb') as file:
        file.write(download.content)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Этот блок у меня отвечает за скачивание картинок, но когда процесс завершается некоторые картинки просто не открываются, хотя если их скачать из браузера то все нормально

Comment: Откройте блокнотом эти картинки - скорее всего там просто html страница

Comment: Да, там html страница с ошибкой 404, но если это скачать без всяких и прочего, то есть response = requests.get(url).content тогда все нормально

Comment: может быть тысяча и одна проблема. Например, в файле есть лишний пробел или сервер не хочет сильно часто отдавать картинки.